# JDBC Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.close()

Tags: java, jdbc

I use reflect to close resources, just like this

```
public static void closeResource(Object ... resources) throws Exception {
    String methodName = "close";
    for (Object obj : resources){
        System.out.println(obj);
        Method m = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(obj);
    }
}
```

But when I use this method to close PreparedStatement, there is an Exception, just like this

```
JDBCUtils.closeResource(resultSet, connection, preparedStatement);
```

And exception is as follows

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.close()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2613)
    at JDBC.Utils.JDBCUtils.closeResource(JDBCUtils.java:45)
    at JDBC.Query.jobsQueryTest.query(jobsQueryTest.java:63)
    at JDBC.Query.jobsQueryTest.main(jobsQueryTest.java:22)
```

The first two resources have been closed success,but the last one is failed.

I try to print object of PreparedStatement(java.sql.PreparedStatement), but output is **com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement**

I feel very confused.

Comment: Why are you using this, and not just use try-with-resources? Also, consider using `AutoCloseable`  instead of `Object`  and reflection.

Comment: Closing the connection probably closes the statement as well. Also , there is no close() method on ```ClientPreparedStatement``` class.

Comment: In any case, you'll probably need to use `getMethod`, because `getDeclaredMethod` only returns methods declared in the class itself, not  methods declared and implemented in superclasses or superinterfaces.

Comment: What's the relation between ClientPreparedStatement and PreparedStatement

Comment: [`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/ClientPreparedStatement.java) is an implementation of `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. However, it doesn't declare `close()`, because that is already implemented in its parent class `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl`. But I repeat again, that you shouldn't using things like that `JDBCUtils.closeResource`. Use try-with-resources instead.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, don't use reflection, but rather if you know the type of resources that you want to close, you can cast them to their respective Interfaces which allow `close()`:

`ClientPreparedStatement` does `implements Statement`, so this should work:

```
public static void closeResource(Object... resources) throws SQLException {
    for (Object obj : resources) {
        if (obj instanceof Statement) {
            Statement statement = (Statement) obj;
            statement.close();
        }
        if (obj instanceof Connection) {
            Connection connection = (Connection) obj;
            connection.close();
        } else {
            //Log to see if you missed any resource;
        }
    }
}
```

As Mark suggested, please refactor your code to Try-with-Resources.  This way Java closes everything for you, you don't have to worry about resource leak.

```
    String sql = "SELECT ...";
    String connectionURL = "";

    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
         PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        ps.setString(1, "12345");

        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //Log e
    }
```

Comment: In the first solution, you can also check `obj instanceof AutoCloseable`, as `java.sql.Connection` and `java.sql.Statement` both extend it.